Why would javsascript think a global variable is undefined
I'm writing a function to check if a table on the page is empty and insert rows with or without a header as appropriate.
The code on the page itself is:
  <div id='uncoveredServices' style='display: none;'>

    <h2>Uncovered services</h2>

    <table id='tblServices'></table>
    <button type='button' id='btnSave' name='btnSave'>Save</button>

  </div>

  <div id='testDiv'>Test Text</div>

  <script src='js/addshortage.js'></script>
  <script src='js/diagramfunctions.js'></script>

The javascript is:
// Get the main table we will use to store all these shortages
var lstServices = document.getElementById('tblServices');

function transferService(btnSelected) {

  // If the table is empty, show the schedules div and add some headers
  if (lstServices.rows.length == 0) {

    document.getElementById('testDiv').innerHTML = 'Success';

  } else {
    document.getElementById('testDiv').innerHTML = 'Failure';
  }

}

The function is called from a button elsewhere on the page:
<button type="button" data-uid="G30291" data-from="2024-06-03" data-stp="P" data-tomorrow="0" data-terminates="LEEDS" onclick="transferService(this)">Select</button>

There are several of these, created by a search function. This allows the user to search for services, and then pick the matching one.
Screenshot showing sample error:

When I run this, it tells me that 'lstServices' is undefined. I've tried referencing other elements on the page which are declared in the same way and they work fine. I've even tried getting rid of the 'display: none' (I was desperate) but I can't work out what's going on!
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Does it tell you that it's undefined or that it's null?

It says lstServices is undefined in the browser console.

How and when is that function called?  When I remove the function, I can't reproduce your results.  console.log(lstServices.rows.length == 0) returns true.  Please edit your question and provide a minimal, reproduceable example of the problem.

The most common reason is that the script to access lstServices is executed before the HTML element for it has been processed to created the table in the DOM. Say, by executing the script in the head section of the HTML document. I can't reproduce your results either.

I did wonder about that, but the table lstServices appears before the link to the script - and other elements in the document work fine. That's what's really confusing me. I've tried putting the links right at the bottom of the document and it still doesn't work.

"Screenshot showing sample error:" - there appears to be a different error, but from the same script file, above this, which we can't completely see. Have you tried eliminating that one first? Plus, some browser extension apparently is also doing something in your page there, according to that source map error message. Test in a private browser tab with extensions disabled, to verify that this isn't somehow contributing to your issue.

The other error you mentioned is what was causing it - although not directly related, it obviously got hung up on that and never got to reading my variable declaration. Commenting out that solved the problem! Many thanks!

The browser doesn't always parse HTML & Javascript in the way you might expect.
I have 2 suggestions for you:

Open Chrome Devtools -> Go to Performance Panel -> Start Recording -> Hard-refresh page -> Stop recording. The resulting graph will breakdown when and where each script is loaded, parsed, and executed. You can see all your DOM events, and lots of other really useful info.
Try adding defer to your Javascript script tags to ensure it will only be executed after the browser finishes parsing all HTML.

#2 does technically introduce a potential problem if the button is clicked before the Javascript is loaded, in which case you might hide the button by default until the DOMContentLoaded event is emitted, for example.
